Subspaces of a matrix inequality that contain solutions
I have a matrix inequality where
$$
a \leq v_1 x_1 + v_2 x_2 + \ldots + v_n x_n \leq b
$$
I want to find subsets of the vectors (i.e. subspaces) that contain valid solutions. Something like:
$$
solutions = \{\{v_4,v_{102},v_{1001}\},\{v_4,v_{12},v_{42},v_{107},v_{1001}\}, \ldots \}
$$
This is different than just solving an inequality because in an inequality, I'm looking for values of $x$
My application is that I'm trying to find the combinations of foods that satisfy a person's dietary needs. I have a dataset from the USDA of about 1,200 foods, each containing 29 nutrients, and am trying to find subsets that a person can grow to sustain themselves - so, ideally I'm looking for the smallest subsets. My current attempts using a numerical solver library haven't proven feasible so far.
To give a simplified example:

Suppose a person's nutritional needs require between 10 and 20 units of Vitamins A, B, and C.
Suppose there are 4 foods to choose from:

Food A containing 1 unit of Vitamin A
Food B containing 1 unit of Vitamin B
Food C containing 1 unit of Vitamin C
Food D containing 1 unit of Vitamin B and 1 unit of Vitamin C



Then
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
10 \\
10 \\
10
\end{bmatrix}
\leq
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
0 \\
0
\end{bmatrix}
x_1 + 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
1 \\
0
\end{bmatrix}
x_2 + 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
0 \\
1
\end{bmatrix}
x_3 +
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
1 \\
1
\end{bmatrix}
x_4
\leq \begin{bmatrix}
20 \\
20 \\
20
\end{bmatrix}
$$
So the solutions would be
$$
solutions = \{
\{
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
0 \\
0
\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
1 \\
0
\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
0 \\
1
\end{bmatrix}
\},
\{
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
0 \\
0
\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
1 \\
1
\end{bmatrix}
\}
\}
$$
That is, you can either grow Foods A, B, and C, or you can grow Foods A and D. The exact quantities of the foods needed to satisfy the nutritional requirements (i.e the conditions of the inequality) is not important.
As noted in the comments {A, B, C, D}, {A, B, D}, and {A, C, D} are also solutions. Ideally, I am looking for minimal sets in the sense that if I'm growing Food D, there's no reason to also grow Food B or Food C. But, for the purpose of this question, finding the minimal set isn't necessary. If I can find all sets, it shouldn't be hard to filter that down to the minimal sets.

Can you use simple example e.g. $n=3$ to describe your idea?

Excellent suggestion. I should have done that originally. I have updated my question. Thanks.

How big is the dimension of the vector space in your application?

Each food contains values for 29 nutrients. Good question. I have edited my question above.

Can you clarify why you don't consider growing ${A, B, D}$ or ${ A, B, C, D }$ a solution? IE Are you looking for a "minimal set" to some extent? I initially read "I want to find subsets of the vectors (i.e. subspaces) that contain valid solutions" as "Find the support set of all solutions". I do see a subsequent, buried phrasing of "ideally I'm looking for the smallest subsets", which suggests this "minimal set" idea.

Ideally, if I grow Food D, I don't want the unnecessary complication of having to grow Food B or C. But, a solution that finds all sets is also fine. I have made edits above.
